# New version of library synchronized with jcenter

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I have a library in Bintray synchronized with JCenter. https://bintray.com/bmsolution/Android/RestManager/0.2

But when I uploaded new version by gradle plugin - it is on Bintray ([link](https://dl.bintray.com/bmsolution/Android/pl/bms/network/)) but it isn't on jcenter ([link](https://jcenter.bintray.com/pl/bms/network/))

**Do you have to wait for synchronization so long or do I do something wrong?**

Fragment of my gradle file responsible for upload:

```
def libVersion = "0.2"

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'pl.bms'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'network'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = libVersion
}


apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blundell/release-android-library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/network-release.aar")
            groupId PUBLISH_GROUP_ID
            artifactId PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID
            version PUBLISH_VERSION


            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                // Iterate over the implementation dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    // Ensure dependencies such as fileTree are not included in the pom.
                    if (it.name != 'unspecified') {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')
    publish = true
    publications = ['MyPublication']
    override = true
    pkg {
        repo = "Android"
        name = "RestManager"
        userOrg = 'bmsolution'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/libandroid/rest-manager"
        issueTrackerUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/libandroid/rest-manager/issues"

        version {
            name = libVersion
            released  = new Date()
            vcsTag = libVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing a similar issue, though in my case it's an additional module which may play part. Unless you changed your artifact ID such that the path would differ between 0.1 and 0.2 then I don't think you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change any group/artifactId, then based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669291/trouble-downloading-my-published-files-on-bintray-from-jcenter) I'd recommend to wait ~24 hours for it to syncronize and then contact support@jfrog.com.

If you changed your group/artifactId then you to relink bintray and jcenter which could also be done with a mail to support or by republishing.

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait if you haven't changed the group and artifact ID.